Abort progress bar in tkinter
I build up a progress bar using tkinter, and I build an "abort" bottom to stop it. Here I used a global variable "isAbort" to control the function. However it fails QQ.
Does anyone know how to make it work?
The code has been revised,thanksJRiggles's suggestion.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("300x400")

isAbort = False

def ProgressBarRunning():
    global isAbort
    
    total_time = 30
    for i in range(total_time):
        if isAbort:
            bar['value']=0
            root.update()
            break
        else:
            bar['value'] = int(100*(i+1)/total_time)
            time.sleep(1)
            root.update()

def AbortProgress():
    global isAbort
    
    print("Abort process...")
    isAbort = True


bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=200, mode="determinate")
bar.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=("W","E"))

run_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=ProgressBarRunning)
run_btn.grid(column=1, row=2)

Abort_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Abort", command=AbortProgress)
Abort_btn.grid(column=2, row=2)

root.mainloop()


What is the point of the isAbort variable?  You never actually check its value...

ProgressBarRunning never checks to see if isAbort is True

Also, you should avoid using sleep in a tkinter app (or any GUI app, really) because the UI will hang as long as the main thread is sleeping. Instead, you should use tkinter's builtin after method.

As commented by JRiggles- avoid using sleep in tkinter apps because it freezes the app. You can for example use the after() method of tkinter along with a recursive function instead of time.sleep():
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("300x400")

isAbort = False

def ProgressBarRunning(progress=0):
    global isAbort

    if isAbort:
        print("Progress aborted.")
        return

    total_time = 30
    bar['value'] = int(100 * progress / total_time)
    if progress < total_time:
        root.after(1000, ProgressBarRunning, progress + 1)
    else:
        print("Progress completed.")

def AbortProgress():
    global isAbort
    isAbort = True

    # Optionally, reset progress bar on abort
    bar['value'] = 0

bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=200, mode="determinate")
bar.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=("W","E"))

run_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=ProgressBarRunning)
run_btn.grid(column=1, row=2)

Abort_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Abort", command=AbortProgress)
Abort_btn.grid(column=2, row=2)

root.mainloop()

The root.after() method schedules the ProgressBarRunning function to be called after 1000 milliseconds (1 second), allowing the GUI to remain responsive by not blocking the main tkinter event loop.

Thanks for the suggestion, it's a good way to prevent the programming dead.
